# How to reuse an InstancePerRequest instance create in composition root using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an Asp.NET MVC5 application in which I registre my types using Autofac in Startup class in this way:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        IContainer container = null;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register Services
        builder.RegisterType<SalesRepository>().As<ISalesRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SalesService>().As<ISalesService>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
           .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandle<>))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register<IAppEvents>(_ => new AppEvents(container)).InstancePerRequest();

        // Register MVC Controllers
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
    }
}
```

These are my services (this is a simplified scenario, only for demonstration).
The SalesService class receives a ISalesRepository interface as dependency . In addition I have an AppEvents class where I want to resolve IHandle types:

```
public interface ISalesRepository { }
public class SalesRepository : ISalesRepository
{
    public SalesRepository() { }
}

public interface ISalesService { }
public class SalesService : ISalesService
{
    ISalesRepository _repo;
    public SalesService(ISalesRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
}

public interface IHandle<T>
{
    void Handle();
}

public class SalesActionHandle : IHandle<string>
{
    ISalesRepository _repo;
    public SalesActionHandle(ISalesRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Handle() { }
}

public interface IAppEvents
{
    void Raise<T>();
}

public class AppEvents : IAppEvents
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AppEvents(IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Raise<T>()
    {
        var handlers = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<T>>>(); // Runtime error here
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.Handle();
    }
}
```

And this is my only (simplified) controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ISalesService _service;
    IAppEvents _events;

    public HomeController(ISalesService service, IAppEvents events)
    {
        _service = service;
        _events= events;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _events.Raise<string>();
        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I get an error at this line when it is executed:

```
var handlers = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<T>>>();
```

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

I resolve it by doing this:

```
public void Raise<T>()
{
    using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
    {
        var handlers = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<T>>>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.Handle();
    }
}
```

But in this case, when IHandle is resolved (with `SalesActionHandle` instance), a new instance of `SalesRepository` is passed as parameter in `SalesActionHandle` constructor. What I want is to "reuse" the same instance that `SalesService` is using (it was created when `ISalesService` was resolved. I want the same `SalesRepository` instance for the request)

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?
The sample code is avaible in Github: https://github.com/josmonver/AutofacTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use
    `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope`
to match your current request scope, but not to create a new request scope.

Comment: It works. I can inject a ILifetimeScope (AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope) in the AppEvents constructor: `public AppEvents(ILifetimeScope scope)` so the AppEvents class has no dependency on Autofac.Integration.Mvc (and its dependencies):
`builder.Register<IAppEvents>(_ => new AppEvents(AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope)).InstancePerRequest();`